# A word/phrase for "honouring (an enquiry)"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There was no response to an enquiry that I sent to someone. If I'm to bring this up in some place else, I would like it to sound similar to this sentence...

> "They didn't even *honour the enquiry with an answer*...".

I'm looking for a better word/phrase to use instead of 'honour'. Something that would mean the enquiry was not even given the minimum respect it should've received. I've seen this type of usage before, but having a hard time recollecting the exact word/phrase. Would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Have you looked up _honour_ or _honor_ as a verb?  Were the synonyms not what you're looking for?  Doing some research on your own and posting the results is expected.

Comment: I would go with 'acknowledge' as in 'They didn't even acknowledge the enquiry'.

Answer (score 1):

*They didn't even **have the courtesy to** reply.*

> to be polite enough to do something. This expression is often used when you are annoyed because someone has not behaved politely
>   *You might have had the courtesy to return my calls.* ([MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-the-courtesy-to-do-something))

A strong idiom could be used: *They couldn't even **give me the time of day***.

> to refuse to speak to someone because you do not like them or because you think you are better than them. *He's so arrogant, he won't even give you the time of day.* ([The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+time+of+day))

Answer (score 0):

> "They didn't even ***regard*** the enquiry ***worth*** an answer...".

ODO:

> **[regard](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/regard)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Consider or think of (someone or something) in a specified way.
>
> ‘I regard this statement of considerable importance; it sets the
>   background against which it is crucial to consider the issues in the
>   case.’
>
> **[worth](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worth)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   **2** [predicative] Sufficiently good, important, or interesting to be treated or regarded in the way specified.
>
> ‘I have always **regarded** this newspaper as an important service and
>   **worth my money** every semester.’